# list files in ascending order

Tags: ls

I am trying to display file names(with complete path)  based on the created timestamp in ascending order. 
if files exists: display files with complete directory path in asc order.
if files do not exists: display nothing.

But first line in output displays "total xxxx".  (I don't want this one)

```
ls -ltr /dir1/subdir1 | awk '{print $9}'
```

Comment: Thank you. would it be possible to get the list line by line.

Comment: `ls -1trd /dir1/subdir1/*`. Try `man ls`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `-l` option to make `ls` sort by modification time.

To remove the “total …” line, pipe through `tail -n +2` (start printing at the second line, i.e. skip the first line).

```
ls -tr /dir/subdir1 | tail -n +2
```

Note that this uses the modification time, not the creation time. Most unix variants don't store the creation time, and anyway it's a dubious concept (there's an ambiguity between modifying a file, and creating a new file which is moved on top of the existing one).